# Is there any way to join attributes between same object in Elastic seach?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an index that will give me profile JSON based on an id. In the JSON I have two different keys with object One key as primary_address object with address_id and another key as Address object with. address id card.
I want to add a join between the address_id of both objects to filter data.

tried with

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                            .filter(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(fieldName))
                            .filter(QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script("doc['primary_address.id'].value == doc['addresses.addr_id'].value")))
                            .filter(setQuery);
```

but its not fetching any results. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This query works. You can try a single bool filter query.

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
              "source": "doc['f1'].value == doc['f2'].value",
              "lang": "painless"
            },
            "boost": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```